# pagination - how to calculate offset for next button if at the last set of records use mod and div?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination, max, min

I am writing manual pagination and not using a paginate gem.
I wish to calculate 'previous' and 'next' buttons.

Previous is pretty easy, I can use

```
<% @previous_images_offset = [@current_offset - 4, 0].max %>
```

However "next" is more tricky, I have tried

```
<% @next_images_offset = [@current_offset + 4, @total_image_count].min %>
```

but that is wrong - if there are 13 images and my current offset is 9 it will gives me [13,13].min which is 13, but I really want 9 in this case as I am already "at the end".

I think I need to use mod and div but I am not sure of the right formula.

Maybe [@current_offset + 4, ((object.size - (object.size DIV 4)*4)].min would work?

Answer (score 2):

If you are at @current_offset == 9 and each page shows 4, then there should be no "next" page.

Out of curiosity, why aren't you using an existing pagination gem?  Someone has already done this work for you.

Comment: because this is part of a much larger page and I have been instructed to do the pagination manually.

Comment: You are correct, there should be no "next page".  I was thinking that on the last 'page' (it's actually as small section of a larger page), the 'next' button would stay on that page.  But maybe I shouldn't have a next button in this case.

Comment: and maybe I shouldn't have a 'previous' button if on the first page.  But you can probably see another issue here - buttons are appearing and disappearing as I navigate around.  Maybe this is ok?  Opinions

Comment: Ah, sometimes you gotta do what you're told.  I know how that is. You could have a disabled "previous" and "next" links when on the first or last page.  That way elements aren't disappearing from the UI.

Comment: What I may do is hide the image.  I will have to see if it jumps around or if I need to reserve space.  I am also using prototype and ruby on rails so my options are good.